# Ability of External Javascript to Determine Referer?

Tags: javascript

Simple scenario:

1) User is on Page A and clicks a link to Page B.
2) User arrives to Page B.
3) An external (hosted on another domain C) Javascript is called when the user is on Page B in this or similar fashion:

```
<script src="http://www.domainC.com/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

4) Is there any way for script.js to tell that the user came to Page B from Page A?

Thanks!

Comment: Just look at the headers your browser sends and answer your question yourself

Comment: @zerkms — Client side scripts do not have direct access to the HTTP headers used to request the document.

Comment: I think @zerkms is saying the server that serves the `script.js` file can read the headers. I don't think that is what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

The remote script is executed within the context of Page B so it can access its global scope.

```
document.referrer
```